# Get point by ID from highchart with multiple series

Tags: highcharts

I looked around a bit but can't seem to find the exact answer for this.

I'm currently adding some data to highcharts. Essentially, I am using the HighStock column and candlestick chart, and it should suffice for my testing.

The issue is this.  I've set up ONE of the two series' to have IDs.  I would now like to retrieve an individual point object by calling [something].get("point_0"), which seems like it should be possible but doesn't seem to work.  Here is the fiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mr3ezgh9/

and here is the code:

```
var chart = null;
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]],

        i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push(
            {
                name: data[i][0],
                x: data[i][0], // the date
                y: data[i][5], // the volume
                color: "red",
                id: "point_" + i
            }
        );
    }


    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
    alert(Highcharts.charts[0].get("point_0"));
});
});
```

I have tried a few variations on .get("point_0") like getting a series first (but the series doesn't have a get function), setting the chart to a variable and then getting it, and other similar changes, but nothing quite seems to work.  Any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem is that in the highstock you have enabled datagrouping, so points are groupped and ids are skipped. Disable it and option will work.

```
 plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mr3ezgh9/1/

Comment: Well, this answer works, but unfortunately that means that I have a whole new question. If it'll fit here, is there a way to target a specific bar that a point belongs to?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible defaulty, obviosuly you can try to develop it on your own by prepareing [approximation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation)